# How to calculate the % for the picklist field in the reports and Dashboard

Tags: reporting, dashboard, report-chart

Hi I have created a Report to show the no of cases created for today. In that we have a Custom picklist field Was Tier tier2 Assistance is Required? the values for the field is 'Yes','No'. the challenge iam facing is to create a formula that displays the % of cases that required the Tier2 Assistance. the condition is I need the % of case that has Was Tier tier2 Assistance is Required?==Yes.

To create a % in Formula field, We do not have the Custom picklist field as a summary field.

Is there any way to bring out the % in the reports.

Comment: Have you looked into the power of one?  That might do the trick for this.

Comment: @Dan I tried this but I could not get the exact result.

Comment: @Dan I came up with a solution. Hope this will help for someone who face the same problem as I faced. I created a Checkbox field and a Workflow to make the checkbox checked if Wastier2Picklist ==Yes. after that I created a summary Formula field in the report saying "Case.WasTier2Require__c:SUM/RowCount" this gives me exact % of cases that requires Tier2 Assistance from all the cases that was created today.

Comment: Good to  hear, if you want to make it a bit lighter you can make it so a formula field where If(Text(Wastier2Picklist)='Yes',1,0) so that workflow is taken care of in a single formula field that lives on the object.